# how to redirect subdomain to non-www

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I want to remove www. from start of my URL it tried this :

I have found this work for **mydomain.com**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.mydomain\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

If i use **mydomain.net.in** it doesn't work how to get it done?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.net\.in$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.([^.]+\.mydomain\.net\.in)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you first appending www and then removing try with below, it will work for both.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Clear cache beforehand.

Comment: It works if i use **www.mydomain.net.in** but if i use **www.mydomain.net.in/subdirectory** it goes to **mydomain.net.in** (Misses subdirectory)

Comment: You have to clear browser cache before using it should work.

Comment: May be some other rule you have are conflicting because it is working here http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/ you can check.

Comment: If it is not important comment it for while then clear cache and try.